# dygraphs change values/legend background

Tags: javascript, css, dygraphs

I'm using dygraphs on a dark background and can't seem to get the background on the legends/values to be transparent.

CSS I've tried:

```
.dygraph-legend {
  background:none;
}
```

and

```
.dygraph-legend {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

I can't find a way to make this transparent.

Link to an image of the problem: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpg2m.png)

Answer (score 4):

dygraphs sets some inline styles on the legend `<div`>. To override them, you need to use `!important`:

```css
.dygraph-legend {
  background: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another div right after the dyGraphs div and tell the graph to use this div for labels and style the labels div with the `!important` annotation. E.g.:

CSS:

```
.dyStatsLegend {
color: silver !important;
background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.1 ) !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dyGraphHumTemp" class="dyStatsDiv"></div>
<div id="dyGraphHumTempLabels" class="dyStatsLegend"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var g1 = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("dyGraphHumTemp"),
    data,{
        labelsDiv: 'dyGraphHumTempLabels'
    });
```